# How do i add register validation into this PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

How do i add register validation so that user wont be able to use the same user id as others? I'm stuck here as I have tried every code and nothing would work. And it will crash my app.

I'm using Eclipse to do my app.

### My php file

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request

 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_pwd'])){

    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pwd = $_POST['user_pwd'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO doc_user (user_name, user_pwd) VALUES('$user_name', '$user_pwd')");


     // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


}
```

Comment: I don't see any user id in the above code. I don't see any errors posted that apparently "crash" your code. I also don't see "every" code that you tried. Do you expect someone to do the work for you so you can copy paste it or are you genuinely interested in solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part in your code

```
// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// chack database
$result = mysql_query("select user_name from doc_user where user_name = '$user_name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "username not available.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO doc_user (user_name, user_pwd) VALUES('$user_name', '$user_pwd')");
```